# Div elements of different width, stack subsequent divs on shorter column

Tags: html, css

I want to organize data in two columns of equal width, but they may be different heights per element. It's difficult to explain, but if you have `div1` of `height 500` and `div2` of `height 400`, then add `div3` of any height, it should appear directly below `div2` rather than `div1` because `div2` is shorter. However, if `div1` was shorter, `div3` would instead appear below it.

Originally I was using tables since it's mostly tabular data, but when one of the two text fields are longer than the either (one in left vs. one in right), it stretches the shorter to match the height. I end up with rows of different height, and the element in the shorter column will stretch to fit that row (which is determined by the taller of either element). I don't want it to stretch, I'd rather it stack to minimize blank space.

[Here's a mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfIZa.jpg) of what I'm trying to achieve. At the top you'll see the page with only one element, then below that you'll see with two elements, then below that with three and four elements. The third element goes below the second element because the overall height of the right column is shorter, but the fourth element goes below the first element because after the third is added, the left column is now shorter.

The only site I can think of off the top of my head that uses a similar organization style is Pinterest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This concept on the web is usually refered to as **Masonry**.
Here is a link to a javascript library that can help you implement it.
http://masonry.desandro.com/

This can also be accomplished using FlexBox css for modern Browsers.
That has been addressed in this question: [using flexbox to get pinterest or jQuery masonry layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919147/using-flexbox-to-get-pinterest-or-jquery-masonry-layout)